# How to deploy a model trained with a custom package on Google ML Engine?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml

I'm able to train a scikit-learn model that includes custom functions on Google ML Engine with a call like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "module_name" \
  --job-dir gs://my_bucket/scikit_learn_job_dir \
  --package-path ./my_package/ \
  --module-name my_package.trainer.train \
  --region us-east1 \
  --runtime-version='1.12' \
  --python-version='3.5' \
  --scale-tier BASIC
```

This code trains the model and uploads a pickle file, `model.pkl` to `gs://my_bucket/models`.

However, I get an error when trying to deploy with :

```
gcloud ml-engine versions create "version_name" \
  --model model_name \
  --origin gs://my_bucket/models \
  --runtime-version='1.12' \
  --framework "SCIKIT_LEARN" \
  --python-version='3.5'
```

The error says that `my_package` cannot be loaded. Indeed, I can't find any option equivalent to `--package-path` in the `version create` command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/versions/create).

Comment: So the job is submitted/queued in `ML Engine` right? It would be super helpful if you could post your error logs from jobs in `ML Engine`.

Comment: Hello! The job is submitted in ML Engine and works fine. The `model.pkl` file is created and uploaded to GCS. The problem is when I create a model version from this .pkl file. The version has a red dot instead of a blue check mark and in the version details, the error is "Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/0001/model.pkl. No module named 'my_package'. (Error code: 0)". This was expected, because I didn't send `my_package` with the `version create` call, but I didn't find how to!

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late to respond, but if you trained the model with some custom package, you will also need to provide that same custom package during deployment (the pickle file alone does not have your custom code). That is probably why your deployment failed. Please see [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-prediction-routines) for more information.